# Either locally convex or concave?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functions, derivatives

$z=f(x,y).$

$f$ is differentiable (updated).

Define upper contour set $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|f(x,y)\geq c\}$ where $c$ is a constant.

Let $C=\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ be an index family of measure non-zero sets $U_\alpha$, and $C$ covers $S$:

$$S\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} U_\alpha.$$

*Claim*: there exists a cover $C$ such that for any $\alpha$, either $U_\alpha\cap S$ is a convex set or $U_\alpha\setminus S$ is a convex set.

How to prove this claim?

---

My sketch:

1) Since $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable, the boundary set $bd(S)$ consists of curves that are almost everywhere smooth.

2) We can find a cover $C$ for $bd(S)$ such that each $U_{\alpha}\cap bd(S)$ is the graph of an almost everywhere differentiable function.

3) Then we can further find a refinement cover $C'=\{U_{\alpha'}:\alpha'\in A'\}$ for each set $U_{\alpha}\cap bd(S)$, such that each $U_{\alpha'}\cap bd(S)$ is either a convex function or a concave function.

Is this sound? I am sure that this can be proved much more elegantly without involving functions, though.

Comment: I guess in order to satisfy the claim we need to impose additional restrictions on $f$. Namely, although the set $A=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: f$ is not differentiable at $(x,y)\}$ has measure zero, the restriction $f|A$ can be very bad (I guess, any function from $A$ to $\Bbb R$), whereas we still need to cover its upper contour set by balls with good intersection, and this can be impossible in general. Moreover, even for so good function $f:\Bbb R to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x,y)=x\sin\tfrac 1x$ for each $x\ne 0$ and $f(0,y)=0$ for each $y\in\Bbb R$ it seems there is no cover satisfying the claim.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks for your comment! I understand your point. If the function $f$ is lipschitz then the claim seems satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the existence of the required cover essentially means that each point $(x,y)\in\Bbb R$ has a neightborhood $U$ such that the restriction $f|U$ is either convex or concave. Unfortunately, this is not alwauys true even for functions of one variable. For intsance, for a function $f(x)=x^3$  at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess your counterexample works for open cover -- $f(x)=x^3$ does not have an open cover that satisfy our requirement. But there is a non-open cover: $\{(-\infty,0],[0,+\infty)\}$

Comment: @HighGPA It is easy to check that for a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, such that $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3$ for each
$(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, for any (closed) ball $(0,0)\in U\subset\Bbb R^2$ a restriction $f|U$ is not 
convex and not concave.

Comment: You are right! The counterexample in 2D works for cover balls.